# UICollectionView Data being Reordered

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview

I am using a UICollectionView with a modified version of LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout and data within my last two cells are being mixed up.

2 separate images are displayed in each cell, with a label beneath, and when I leave the viewController and return, I call reloadData. Every time this is called, the images in the cells swap. The labels, however, stay in the same place.

Here is the code I use to draw the cells which I have the issue with.

```
SettingsTile *setTileD = (SettingsTile *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"settingsReuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *songTitle = [colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    [query addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:songTitle forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];
    if ([query items].count > 0)
    {
        MPMediaItemArtwork *art = [[[query items] objectAtIndex:0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
        UIImage *im = [art imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(145, 145)];

        setTileD.titleLabel.text = songTitle;
        setTileD.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 145)];
        imView.image = im;
        [setTileD addSubview:imView];
        [setTileD sendSubviewToBack:imView];
        return setTileD;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
```

The first time the app is run the images are mixed up, likely because viewDidAppear is also called when the viewController is first displayed, and when the user comes back to it, the images aren't mixed up. This process repeats itself.

reloadData is called as normal (e.g [collectionView reloadData]; ).

I'm new to UICollectionView, and it's accompanying classes, so please be kind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by putting the UIImageViews in a backgroundView, rather than adding them directly as subviews.

I can only imagine this problem is caused either by the way UICollectionView's cellForRowAtIndexPath: method grabs images as I call them, or the way LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout works.

Comment: Can you please explain, what do you mean by " .. putting the UIImageViews in a backgroundView .."?? Thanks

Comment: I used this to fix a similar issue. In cellForItemAtIndexPath, I used: cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];